# Obtener lineas de un fichero

Tags: java

Buenas tengo una duda quiero que en un fichero me vaya leyendo lineas y las guarde en dos vectores de caracteres y luego comparar la ultima posicion de ambos vectores (que son fechas). Pero no sabria como ponerlo con whiles o con otro tipo de bucles.

```
File f = new File(cadena);
    Scanner b = new Scanner(f);
    while (b.hasNextLine()){
         }
```

Porque si pongo esto y lo guardo en un vector, en cada iteracion se cargaría lo que este dentro de ese vector, pero tampoco sé muy bien como poner b.nextLine() mas 1 para que sea la siguiente a la primera.

Comment: podrías poner un ejemplo del resultado esperado? Por que no se entiende bien

Answer (score -1):

b.nextLine() avanzaría de línea automaticamente, no necesitarías decirle que linea deseas leer.

No acabo de entender del todo como o porque pretendes guardar las lineas en dos vectores distintos, pero voy a tratar de ayudarte en lo que pueda:

Caso 1: Pretendes guardar la misma línea en dos vectores distintos, en este caso, dentro del bucle while deberias añadir una variable que guarde el contenido de la linea, de forma que luego puedas dar el valor de esa variable a los vectores, puesto que si hicieras directamente "vector1[x]=b.nextline() y vector2[x]=b.nextLine()" en realidad estarías guardando líneas distintas.

Caso 2: Pretendes guardar las lineas pares en un vector y las impares en otro ?
De esa manera solo tendrías que hacer un contador y meter un if dentro del while, de forma que si el contador es par vaya a un vector y si es impar al otro.

Espero haberme explicado de forma sencilla, si no entendí tu pregunta y puedes aclararla un poco mejor trataré de ayudarte en lo que pueda